# Why can't I run a WHOIS query on certain sites, such as fbi.gov and thepiratebay.se

Tags: networking, security, whois

Why can't I run a WHOIS query (https://www.whois.net/) on certain sites, such as fbi.gov and thepiratebay.se?

Does the FBI and Pirate Bay server simply block the connection, or are the entries removed from the WHOIS database?

Comment: Only specific entities can register domains ending in .gov (in other words they are not for sale) (sTLD) furthermore .se domains are not restrictive of whom registers them.  The amount of information that can be looked up depends on the domain (ccTLD).  .gov and .mil domains do not have “owners” they are owned by the US government and/or US Military.  Likewise what can be looked up of whom owns .se depends on the requirements of the particular (ccTLD)

Comment: So your question lacks understanding the purpose of these TLDs

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like a proper whois service.  Try command line, or any of the other online whois services:

https://www.whois.com/whois/fbi.gov

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt reply. Using whois.com, I can get only the IP address of the fbi.gov server. Whereas if I give another site, I can get a lot more information. How is this handled?

Comment: 'whois' is a specific protocol that returns the registrant of a domain from a domain registrar, and depending on the service, the primary name servers for a domain.  Some online services will take this a step further and carry out some DNS queries to obtain more info.  This isn't done with the whois service, but standard DNS.  How they handle this is site dependent.